# How to stop Multithreading or How to give request one by one in Scrapy?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline, scrapy-shell

I tried to crawl data of a product in the format.
1) ADD CART
2) VIEW CART
3) REMOVE CART

For single color product it is working perfectly but for multi-color product, Scrapy takes multi-threading so above process is not in order for each and every product.

I want scrapy to request like:

1) 
product A - ADD CART
product A - VIEW CART
product A - REMOVE CART

2) 
product B - ADD CART
product B - VIEW CART
product B - REMOVE CART

3) 
product C - ADD CART
product C - VIEW CART
product C - REMOVE CART

I have used (priority while callback) also but no luck. Assistance will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Show us your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` setting to `1`.

As described in the [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?highlight=concurrent_requests#concurrent-requests):

> CONCURRENT_REQUESTS
>   Default: 16
>   The maximum number of concurrent (ie. simultaneous) requests that will be performed by the Scrapy downloader.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42020851/how-stop-multithreading-or-how-to-give-request-one-by-one-in-scrapy

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42020851/how-stop-multithreading-or-how-to-give-request-one-by-one-in-scrapy.                                                My code will be above path

Comment: i have tried CONCURRENT_REQUESTS  in custom_settings but it works for parent color url of a product alone not for child color url of a product.